# SQLException: no such column with has many through join

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to select all admin users from my join table "Memberships". I just need to select all users from Memberships where group id is x and membership role is admin.

```
@admins = User.joins(:memberships).where(["memberships.group_id ? and memberships.role ?", @group.id, "admin"])
```

The problem is instead of trying to look at memberships.role, it is saying there is no such thing as users.role. How do I get this to look for the membership role?

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: users.role: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "memberships" ON "users"."id" = "memberships"."user_id" WHERE "memberships"."group_id" = ? AND "users"."role" = ?
```

*memberships table in schema:*

```
  create_table "memberships", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "group_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",             null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",             null: false
    t.integer  "role",       default: 0
    t.index ["group_id", "user_id"], name: "index_memberships_on_group_id_and_user_id", unique: true
    t.index ["group_id"], name: "index_memberships_on_group_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_memberships_on_user_id"
  end
```

*membership.rb*

```
class Membership < ApplicationRecord
  enum role: { member: 0, admin: 1 }

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :group_id, presence: true
end
```

*group.rb*

```
class Group < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :creator, class_name: "User"
  has_many :memberships, dependent:   :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :memberships
```

*user.rb*

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :created_groups, class_name: "Group"
  has_many :memberships, dependent:   :destroy
  has_many :groups, through: :memberships
```

Comment: I see a `COUNT` in your `SQL` query but the `ActiveRecord` query suggests there is no `count`. Is that the right query?

Comment: Yes, that is the exact query from the controller.

Comment: There is something isn't right in your query. Try this `@admins = User.joins(:memberships).where(["memberships.group_id = ? and memberships.role = ?", @group.id, "admin"])`

Comment: I see the difference between the two queries. I still get that error, though. `SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: users.role: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "memberships" ON "users"."id" = "memberships"."user_id" WHERE "memberships"."group_id" = ? AND "users"."role" = ?`

Comment: Ok. I got it. It should be `@admins = User.joins(:memberships).where("memberships.group_id = ? and memberships.role = ?", @group.id, "admin")`. You should remove the `[]`

Comment: Same error. I don't get why it's looking for users.role instead of memberships.role.

Comment: Sorry. Thats right actually.

Comment: What do you get from `Membership.where(:group_id => @group.id, :role => "admin")` ?

Comment: So that works to get the membership, I could loop through the membership records where the group_id matches and the users are admins, but I need to pull all the users who are admin, not the memberships only.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried? If you have defined correctly has_many and belongs_to it should work, maybe it's the simpliest solution

```
User.memberships.where(group_id: @group.id, role: "admin")
```